# Loop or function to make changes in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python loop or function to make changes in multiple dataframes (with same headers).

The following loop does not work:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('D1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('D2.csv')


P1=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
T1=['t1','t2','t3','t4']

df_list = [df1, df2]
for df in df_list:
 #summarize P1 & T1 and store to new columns
    df['P'] = df[P1].sum(axis=1)
    df['T'] = df[T1].sum(axis=1)

#drop initial columns P1 & T1
    df=df.drop(df[P1],axis=1)
    df=df.drop(df[T1],axis=1)
#filter and rename
    df = df[df['C'].isin([1,2])]
    df.rename(columns={'A1': 'A','B1: 'B','C1': 'C'}, inplace=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter(Book1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='D1')
     df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='D2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would probably raise a `KeyError` when calling [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and/or a `SyntaxError` when calling [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

Try this :

```
for df in df_list:
    #summarize P1 & T1 and store to new columns
    df['P'] = df[P1].sum(axis=1)
    df['T'] = df[T1].sum(axis=1)

    #drop initial columns P1 & T1
    df = df.drop(columns= P1+T1)
    
    #filter and rename
    df = df[df['C'].isin([1,2])]
    df.rename(columns={'A1': 'A', 'B1': 'B','C1': 'C'}, inplace=True)
```

Or in one bloc :

```
for df in df_list:
    df= (
            df
             .assign(P = df[P1].sum(axis=1),
                     T = df[T1].sum(axis=1))
             .drop(columns= P1+T1)
             .loc[lambda x: x['C'].isin([1, 2])]
             .rename(columns={'A1': 'A', 'B1': 'B','C1': 'C'})
         )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! If i run the code without loops or functions I am not getting any errors. But running the shared codes I am getting a Valueerror: This sheet is too large

Comment: Are you using `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` ? If so, what dataframe are you trying to save as a spreadsheet ? Also, can you `print(mydf.shape)` ? _assuming `mydf` is the concerned dataframe_.. Anyway, you need to add your full code to your post/question.

Comment: Thanks, just posted the full code!

Comment: Can you add the `print(df1.hape)` and `print(df2.hape)` ?

Comment: Yes it is (1437049, 44) & (1437051, 44)

Comment: There is an Excel limitation : __1 048 576__ for rows et __16 384__ for columns. Are your `df1` and `df2` really this big ?

Comment: Yes this is the size of csv files. Although without loops the code runs smoothly but i have to write it multiple times for each df

Comment: Really? For me, It is impossible to save a dataframe (having a shape `(1437049, 44)`) in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The final output after applying filters it should be ~20 - 30k rows. Do you know if there is any way to save it?